# Numbers saved in Django session automatically rounded down when computing item sub totals

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, rounding

I have pricing data saved in my model like:

```
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4, default=None)
```

When I render the numbers, they show up as expected: 12.0, 10.75 etc. When I attempt to calculate totals and subtotals for items in my cart, it rounds down anything with a decimal point. So when I am trying to get a total for 2 items at $10.75, it will give me $20 when I want $21.50. How can I fix this? I figure it has something to do with the way I'm saving it to sessions. Here is my sessions data:

```
class Cart(object):


    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session


        if not hasattr(settings, 'CART_SESSION_KEY'):
            raise KeyNotSet('Session key identifier is missing in settings')

        if not hasattr(settings, 'PRODUCT_MODEL'):
            raise KeyNotSet('Product model is missing in settings')

        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_KEY)

        if not cart:
            is_model_set = hasattr(settings, 'USE_CART_MODELS')
            if is_model_set and settings.USE_CART_MODELS:
                # cart =
                pass
            else:
                cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_KEY] = {}

        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, price, quantity=1,):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'price': int(price), 'quantity': 0}

        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = int(quantity)
        self.save()



        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = int(quantity)
        self.save()


    def save(self):
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_KEY] = self.cart
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()



    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()

        splitted = settings.PRODUCT_MODEL.split('.')
        app_label = splitted[0]
        model_name = splitted[1]

        try:
            model = apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)
        except LookupError:
            message = 'Model {} not found in app  {}'
            raise ModelDoesNotExist(message.format(model_name, app_label))

        products = model.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())


    @property
    def total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    @property
    def item_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())


    def clear(self):
        self.session.cart[settings.CART_SESSION_KEY] = {}
        self.session.modified = True
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
I changed the way I was adding the numbers to my cart from an integer to decimal.decimal. I'm now receiving a type error: `Object of type Decimal not json serializable`. Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback:

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
35.
response = get_response(request)

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
97.
response = self.process_response(request, response)

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py" in process_response
58.
request.session.save()

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in save
81.
obj = self.create_model_instance(data)

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in create_model_instance
68.
session_data = self.encode(data),

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in encode
96.
serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py" in dumps
87.
return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py" in dumps
238. ** kw).encode(obj)

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py" in encode
199.
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py" in iterencode
257.
return _iterencode(o, 0)

File
"C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\json\encoder.py" in default
180.
o.__class__.__name__)

Exception
Type: TypeError
at / cart / add / 4009
Exception
Value: Object
of
type
'Decimal' is not JSON
serializable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're converting the price to an `int` in the `add()` method:

```
self.cart[product_id] = {'price': int(price), 'quantity': 0}
```

That would have the effect of rounding the price down to the nearest integer.

Since you are already converting the price to a `Decimal` in `total_price()`, you can store the value in the session as a string.

```
self.cart[product_id] = {'price': str(price), 'quantity': 0}
```

Comment: Changing it to `decimal.Decimal` didn't work unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you still seeing the rounding, even with `decimal.Decimal`?

Comment: Ok, think I found out why it's happening. Instead of refreshing my page, I had to clear my cart and add a new item. I got an error: Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable.

Comment: Updating code with the traceback. Relatively new, so I guess this may be a whole different issue that I have to fix. Thank you.

Comment: I'd missed the fact that `total_price()` already converts the price to a `Decimal`. I've updated my answer to indicate that you should be able to store the price in the session as a string - which is JSON serializable.